# Case statement with extglob

Tags: bash

With *extglob* on, I want to match a variable against

```
*( )x*
```

(In regex: `/^ *x.*/`)

This:

```
main(){
  shopt -s extglob
  local line=' x bar'
  case "$line" in
    *( )x*) ;;
    *) ;;
  esac
}
main "$@"
```

is giving me a syntax error. Either removing the extglob parentheses or moving `shopt -s extglob` outside of `main`, to the outer scope, fixes the problem.
Why? Why does the `shopt -s extglob` command need to be outside?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

bash has to parse the function in order to create it, and since the extended glob syntax you're using would normally be invalid, it can't parse the function unless extglob is on *when the function is created*.

Net result: extglob has to be on both when the function is declared *and* when it runs. The `shopt -s extglob` line in the function takes care of the second requirement, but not the first.

BTW, there are some other places where this can be a problem. For example, if you have a `while` or `for` loop, bash needs to parse the entire loop before beginning to run it. So if something in the loop uses extglob, you have to enable it before the beginning of the loop.

Comment: In short, `shopt -s extglob` must be called BEFORE the function declaration, right ?

Comment: @SebMa Right. And then you also need to *not* do `shopt -u extglob` (turning off extended globs) before calling the function (or if you do that, turn extended globbing back on while the function runs).

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `in` keyword.

```
case "$var" in
    *( )x*) echo yes;;
esac
```