# Bash shell syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: bash, shell

Not sure why this script kept getting a syntax error on my CI machine.

```
if [ -d "$ws" ]; then
    if $condition; then
        echo "first condition"
    elif $second_condition; then
        ls -al
        shopt -s extglob
        rm -rf !(".repo")
        ls -al
        $[/myResource/ec.perl] $[/myResource/PWToolRootLocationFull]SetProperty.pl $[/myParent/parent.workflow.path]/builds/$[/myParent/variant.id]/is.repo.preserved "true"
    else
        echo "else"
    fi
fi
```

syntax error near unexpected token `('

I've tried

```
rm -rf !(.repo)
rm -rf "!(.repo)"
rm -rf !\(.repo\)
rm -rf !"(.repo)"
```

None of them are working.

Comment: I get the error only when `shopt -s extglob` is missing.

Comment: @choroba did you use bash shell?

Comment: That's the kind of error you'd get by invoking the script with `sh` instead of `bash`, but then you'd probably get a "shopt: not found" error first. The `$[...]` syntax looks odd: that's bash deprecated syntax for arithmetic expansion -- does it have some kind of special meaning in your CI pipeline?

Comment: If you use `shopt -s extglob`, then `rm -rf -- !(*.repo)` will delete anything in the current directory that doesn't end in `.repo`.

Comment: @glennjackman hmm, this CI pipeline is really old (over 10 years). I won't feel weird if it contains something out of date. I didn't get the "shopt: not found" error tho.

Comment: @CodaChang, ...to repeat the question that was asked earlier: What's up with all the `$[...]`? It makes no sense except when doing arithmetic (and even then it shouldn't be used; the modern standard-compliant syntax -- mandated since the POSIX sh specification was written in 1992 -- is `$(( ))`; `$[ ]` only exists in bash for compatibility with ancient shells from the 70s, but the POSIX spec doesn't require or support it, so it's incompatible with a lot of more recent shells).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the extra option, but I just want to preserve `.repo`. In your way, I think folders like `test.repo` will also be preserved.

Comment: @CodaChang, that's what `rm -rf -- !(*.repo)` _does_. And as I said, you need `shopt -s extglob` to turn on the syntax feature for it to work. `!(".repo")` will delete `test.repo` because it's missing the `*`, so it deletes every filename that isn't _exactly_ `.repo` (since `test.repo` and `.repo` are two different names).

Comment: `shopt -s extglob` should be up near the very top of your script; it can't always just be on a prior line, it has to happen before the parser _starts to parse_ the code with the extglob. If that code is inside a function or other block, whether the `shopt` will take effect in time for other code inside that same block gets muddy. This is, incidentally, what Gordan's answer is already telling you.

Answer (score 3):

The shell has to parse the entire outer `if` statement (and all of its contents) before it can execute it, which means it has to parse that pattern before it executes `shopt -s extglob`. Solution: move `shopt -s extglob` to the very beginning of the script (or at least before the first `if`).

Comment: BTW, this problem is a near-duplicate of the one in ["Case statement with extglob"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34912289/case-statement-with-extglob), except in that case it was a function definition rather than an enclosing `if` block that caused pre-parsing. I'm not sure if it should be marked as a dupe.