# extglob not working in non-interactive shell even when set

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, scripting

```
$ bash -c 'shopt -s extglob ; echo !(foo)' 
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 1: `shopt -s extglob ; echo !(foo)'
```

However

```
$ bash -c 'shopt -s extglob ; shopt|grep extglob'
extglob         on
```

The equivalent code run in a script file works as expected.

Can I get `extglob` to work with `-c`?

Comment: If you replace the semicolon with a newline, it works. So I guess `shopt -s extglob` changes the parser settings for *following lines*, but doesn't affect other commands on the same line.

Comment: @wjandrea thanks, that does work. But I need to run this in a Makefile and so can't use a newline. (Yes our Makefile style-guide prefers using bash over Makefile syntax when possible).

Comment: The [bash wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) mentions this restriction of extglob, btw (and demonstrates a few workarounds)

Comment: `shopt -s extglob` must be *executed* before the commands that use extended globbing are *parsed*. This means you can't put them on the same line, or inside the same complex command (`if...fi`, `while...done`, `{ }`, `( )`, etc), because the shell parses the entire thing before executing any of it. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34912289/case-statement-with-extglob). I don't know of a way to work around this in a makefile.

Comment: Using GNU make: `$(filter-out foo, $(wildcard *))` (while it *is* technically possible to do what you want in a bash one liner (see my earlier link), does a code review have to know that?)

Comment: `bash -cO extglob 'echo !(foo)'` looks like the best solution for me. Any drawbacks? (apart from not being Makefile syntax, posix, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Can this `Makefile` accomplish what you wanted ?

```
SHELL = /usr/bin/env bash -O extglob

target:
    @echo !(foo)
```

Comment: I discussed Makefiles in the comments but I also wanted a solution that could be used outside of Makefiles (original question isn't about Makefiles). Also, I don't want to turn on extglob (and even bash) for the whole Makefile. `bash -cO extglob 'echo !(foo)'` is my preferred option at this point.